# Why does this code report that -31 is greater than 6?

Tags: c++, c

I have a function `double max(int count, ...)` in my program. This function should return the highest number, but it reports that `-31 > 6`. Where is my mistake? I'm trying to learn `va_`. How can I fix this?

```
double max(int count, ...)
{
    double max = INT_MIN, test;

    int i;
    va_list values;
    va_start(values, count);
    for (i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        test = va_arg(values, double);
        if (test > max)
        {
            max = test;
        }
    }
    va_end(values);
    return max;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%ld", max(5, 1, 6, -31, 23, 24));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In C++, you might use type safe variadic template instead of ellipsis.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question does not show signs the poster has done elementary debugging. The simplest `printf` or debugger examination of the values assigned to `test` would have revealed the issue.

Comment: First rule of `va_`, the types used in `va_arg` must match the types passed to the function. In your code this is not true.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are invoking *undefined behavior*. You are not passing in `double` values to `max()`, you are passing in `int` values instead.  `int` and `double` are different sizes in memory, and `va_arg()` can't read an `int` parameter as if it were a `double`, and vice versa.  You need to match the types correctly.

In this example, change all of the `double`s to `int`s, eg:

```
int max(int count, ...)
{
    int max = INT_MIN, test;

    va_list values;
    va_start(values, count);
    for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        test = va_arg(values, int);
        if(test > max)
        {
            max = test;
        }
    }
    va_end(values);
    return max;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d", max(5,1,6,-31,23,24));
    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/DdEOZr)

Otherwise, change the `int`s to `double`s instead, eg:

```
double max(int count, ...)
{
    double max = -DBL_MAX, test;

    va_list values;
    va_start(values, count);
    for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        test = va_arg(values, double);
        if(test > max)
        {
            max = test;
        }
    }
    va_end(values);
    return max;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%lf", max(5,1.0,6.0,-31.0,23.0,24.0));
    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/OfpjUi)

---

Either way, you might consider a slight change in logic in how you are handling the `max` value.  You should initialize it to the 1st value that is passed in, eg:

```
<type> max(int count, ...)
{
    if (count <= 0)
        return <default value>;

    va_list values;
    va_start(values, count);

    <type> max = va_arg(values, <type>), test;

    for(int i = 1; i < count; ++i)
    {
        test = va_arg(values, <type>);
        if (test > max)
        {
            max = test;
        }
    }

    va_end(values);
    return max;
}
```

---

Also, note that all of the above is the C way of handling things. But you also tagged your question as C++, and the C++ way to handle this would be to use a [variadic template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) instead of ellipses (ie, no `va_arg()` needed), or else take a [`std::initializer_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) or at least a pair of `iterator`s so that you can then make use of the standard [`std::max_element()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) algorithm.